# Silex: Adding new values to the session helper

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, session, silex

I'm making a very crude shopping card using and MVC I've created using Silex. I have a JS/AJAX problem. I'm trying to submit a product to the basket. The trouble is, it submits the details, sets them in the session and that works fine. When you add a second product, it replaces the product instead of appending it in an array. I've tried a few different things and to no success. (Code below).

Cheers,

Ewan

Router that takes the ajax values:

```
$app->get('/add/to/cart/{id}/{name}/{price}', function( $id, $name, $price ) use ( $app ) {

$basket[] = array (
    'id'    => $id,
    'name'  => $name,
    'price' => $price
);

$app['session']->set( 'basket', $basket ); 

return new Response( "Added to basket." );

});
```

Here's the javascript

```
$('.add-to-cart').on("click", function() {

$productId  = $(this).attr('product-id');
$productName = $(this).attr('product-name');
$productCost = $(this).attr('product-cost');

$.ajax({  
        type: "GET",  
        url: "http://localhost/php/Test/web/index.php/add/to/cart/"+$productId+"/"+$productName+"/"+$productCost,  
        data: {
            // Doesn't need the data, Silex takes it from the url
        },
        success: function() {  
            // Just to check it worked
            console.log( "add/to/cart/"+$productId+"/"+$productName+"/"+$productCost );
        },  
        error: function() { 

        }  
    }); 
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get the current basket first. Add this to the beginning of your function:

```
$basket = $app["session"]->get("basket", array());
```

The second parameter is the default value, it's returned when no such key exists in the session. This way you get an empty array in this case.

Comment: I had to use an array_merge as well, but spot-on! Thanks for that, it seems so obvious now. You've saved me a lot of time!